# Windows 2003 batch script with pipe

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write a batch script that will run every 15 minutes, check number of files in a directory and if that number is bigger then set limit, move all files to another directory. I would easily do this in bash script, but this is my first batch script.

I split this task in several steps:

1. Find number of files in directory.
   I managed to do this with this command:

   > dir/b/a-d d:\test\test2 | find /v /c "::"
2. Next thing is to assign output of this command to some variable so I can compare it with my desired limit. This is where problem starts.

```
    ECHO OFF
    setlocal enableextensions

    FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%a IN (`dir/b/a-d d:\test\test2 ^| find /v /c "::"`)
    DO (@SET NUMFIL=%%a)
    ECHO %NUMFIL%

    endlocal
```

I'm getting: "| was unexpected at this time". Obviously, pipe is getting in the way. I found that it is special character and as such must be escaped with caret. After doing so, I'm getting: "The syntax of the command was incorrect." This is Windows server 2003.

3.After getting this problem solved, I plan to insert something like this:

```
IF %%NUMFIL%% > 20
(move "d:\test\test2\ti*" "d:\test\test2\dir\")
```

That would move all that files (all of them starts with "ti") to desired directory.

So my questions would be: what to do with #2 issue and will #3 work in this case?

Comment: `FOR` and `DO` are supposed to be on the same line.

Comment: #3: Surprisingly, the compare syntax is explained at `IF /?`

Comment: Thanks indiv, putting it on the same line worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure `"::` will work in your first case, since `::` is unlikely to appear in a DIR output. A single colon would suffice, since the `/c` option of `find` counts the number of LINES in which the target string occurs.

The secret to the second problem is that the `do` keyword must occur on the same line as the closing-parenthesis of the `IN` clause. It is possible to break the structure into

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%a IN (
 ' dir/b/a-d d:\test\test2 ^| find /v /c ":" '
) DO (SET NUMFIL=%%a)
```

Note the `@` is not required - it suppresses the command's being `echo`ed, which is turned off by the initial `@echo off` (the `@` there suppresses the echoing of the `ECHO OFF`

Also, the parentheses around this `set` are not required. IF they are used, the open-parenthesis must occur on the same physical line as the `do`.

You also don't need to use `usebackq` since you have no need here to change the interpretation of quotes.

Third item - `>` is a redirector. For a comparison operator, use one of EQU GEQ LSS LEQ GTR NEQ depending on comparison required.

And again, the open-parenthesis must be on the same line as the `if`. With an `else`, the close-parenthsis before the `ELSE` , the ELSE keyword and the open-parenthesis after must all be on the same physical line.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.  Note that it does not use backticks.

```
ECHO OFF
setlocal enableextensions
FOR /F %%a IN (' dir /b /a-d "d:\test\test2" ^| find /c /v "" ') DO SET NUMFIL=%%a
ECHO %NUMFIL%
IF %NUMFIL% GTR 20 (move "d:\test\test2\ti*" "d:\test\test2\dir\")
```